# How export .DMP file from oracle 12C DB

Tags: plsqldeveloper, oracle12c

> user inside the plugable DB(PDB21) username -'JEWBDEV' and 
>   PWD-abc123, i am not able to export backup .dmp file please suggest
>   steps.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create datapump directory and grant permissions to user

```
SQL> CREATE or REPLACE DIRECTORY dpump_dir as '/home/user1/dumpfiles';
SQL> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY dpump_dir TO JEWBDEV;
```

> 2. Set the environment (outside sqlplus):

```
setenv DATA_PUMP_DIR DPUMP_DIR
```

> 3. Export table (outside sqlplus):

```
expdp JEWBDEV/abc123@pdb21 tables=TABLE1 dumpfile=table1.dmp logfile=jewbdev_exp.log
```

Note, in above examples some of the values like `TABLE1, /home/user1/dumpfiles` are written for example, it needs to be changed according to your requirement.

> 4. Export everything under a schema/user (outside sqlplus):

To export everything under a user you can skip giving the tablenames, following is the format:

```
expdp system/manager@<pluggable_database> file=<user>.dmp owner=<user>
```

Example:

```
expdp system/manager@pdb21 file=JEWBDEV.dmp owner=JEWBDEV
```

Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647408/how-to-export-database-schema-in-oracle-to-a-dump-file) SO question to get better understanding on expdp.

> 5. Working example

Following steps are verified at my end:

```
SQL> show pdbs
    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 CDB1_PDB1                      READ WRITE NO

SQL> alter session set container=cdb1_pdb1;             
Session altered.

SQL> CREATE or REPLACE DIRECTORY dpump_dir as '$T_WORK';
Directory created.
```

Following should be run outside sqlplus:

```
expdp system/manager@cdb1_pdb1 file=scott.dmp owner=SCOTT
```

In your case it will be:

```
expdp system/manager@cdb1_pdb21 file=JEWBDEV.dmp owner=JEWBDEV
```

So, make sure your pdb name is `CDB1_PDB21` when you query `show pdbs`. If the PDB name is `PDB21` then the connect string should change like the following:

```
expdp system/manager@pdb21 file=JEWBDEV.dmp owner=JEWBDEV
```

Also, note that we are exporting the user/schema JEWBDEV with SYSTEM user.

Comment: ,Thank you very much  but i want export whole DB means all table with all object then how will do , here you mentioned tables=select table but i need all table and view ,etc.    please suggest

Comment: I have tried to take export as per your guidance but  its give error ,which is given below'''''''''''''''''[oracle@oracledb ~]$ expdp JWBFADEV/abc123@pdb21  dumpfile=JWBFADEV.dmp logfile=JWBFADEV_exp.log

Export: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Tue Apr 21 08:31:49 2015

Copyright (coffee) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

UDE-12154: operation generated ORACLE error 12154
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified