# How do you export an exact copy of an Oracle database 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, copy

I am using dumps to export the database. The problem is that the dump does not include empty tables. What's the best way to export the complete database, structure and data?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647408/how-to-export-database-schema-in-oracle-to-a-dump-file/23647579#23647579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a data pump. Look up the oracle tool expdp.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g

Answer (score 0):

- thought it was worth mentioning that you could restore a backup - theres a lot of IF's about doing that - but IF you control the environment and IF you can shut down the system while doing it it might be easy to backup your original database and restore it on a similar environment

I use this method to back up my own development environment

```
oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Wed Oct 17 05:39:49 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> shutdown immediate
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ tar czvf spxe-20181017.tar.gz admin/ fast_recovery_area/ oradata/
```

To restore the backup - you just extract the files and replace the existing folders

```
oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ rm -rdf admin/
oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ rm -rdf fast_recovery_area/
oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ rm -rdf oradata/
oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ tar xzvf spxe-20181017.tar.gz 
oracle@befb83f389c6:~$ sqlplus / as sysdba 

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Wed Oct 17 06:13:22 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  601272320 bytes
Fixed Size          2228848 bytes
Variable Size         364907920 bytes
Database Buffers      230686720 bytes
Redo Buffers            3448832 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL>
```